# Appendix B2 of Fourier Analysis on Groups by Walter Rudin

Tags: soft-question

In Appendix B2 of [*Fourier Analysis on Groups* by Walter Rudin](http://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/iosevich/rudingroupsbook.pdf) one can read:

> A *homomorphism* of a group $G$ into a group $G_1$ is a map $\phi$ of $G$ into $G_1$ such that
>   $$\phi\left(x+y\right)=\phi\left(x\right)+\phi\left(y\right)\qquad\left(x,y\in G\right).$$
>   A homomorphism which is one-to-one is an *isomorphism*.

Is it not standard to require $\phi$ to be surjective?

Comment: Do you mean if its standard to require surjectivity for $\phi$ to be an isomorphism? If so, then yes.

Comment: @mathworker21, I assume that this is a typo, then.

Comment: not a typo: see the proof of the theorem in section 4.6.4, for instance

Comment: @user363464, interesting. Then $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb R$ are isomorphic, which implies that such things as the size of the sets is irrelevant in the context of groups.

Comment: no, in the appendix right after the definition you quote, he says two groups are isomorphic if there is an isomorphism of one _onto_ the other.

Comment: Some authors use "one to one" to mean "bijection."